# @font-face working in localhost not in live server

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am using a [font](http://fontzone.net/font-details/Kristen+ITC/)  for my site which is stored under my project folder as **fonts**
and i used this code in css.

**my css**

```
 @font-face
{
font-family: buddys;
src: url('/fonts/Kristen-ITC-Regular.ttf'),
     url('/fonts/Kristen-ITC-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

its working on localhost while its uploaded to live the font style not apply on my site. How to make it work on live site.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you deploying this via Visual Studio, by any chance?

Comment: @AlanShortis : Yes i am using visual studio

Comment: show us a grab of your folder structure, and we can tell you easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using Visual Studio, you need to set the Build Action for each of your webfonts to 'Content' under properties.  If you don't do this, your font files do not get included in the deployment package and never make it to your server.

Also, I would suggest improving your `@font-face` code in your CSS to include all formats (you can use font squirrel to help with this: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).  Also worth a read is this article on the most compatible code to use: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: issue rectified by build the font-files using content

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the actual font is uploaded to your webserver and the path is correct?

I'd suggest specifying all of the image files:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

To generate them all from the font-face file, just use a tool like [this](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your font path is absolute. Check it.

Comment: You would likely want it to be so that the font loads on subpages, but I agree that the URL should be checked.

Comment: Exactly, on linux starting a path with `/` refer to the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

If your css file is in the folder named: 'css' and fonts dir and css dir is in the same folder named 'assets'.

Then:I think your css code should be:

```
 @font-face
{
font-family: buddys;
src: url('../fonts/Kristen-ITC-Regular.ttf'),
     url('../fonts/Kristen-ITC-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```